# Error setting up julia language server in Neovim

Tags: neovim, lsp, mason

When I try to use julials I get the following prompt:

> Client quit with exit code 1 and signal 0
> These are the lsp log

```
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:43] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "ERROR: "
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:43] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    'ArgumentError: Package LanguageServer not found in current path:\n- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("LanguageServer")` to install the LanguageServer package.\n\nStacktrace:'
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:43] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "\n [1] "
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:43] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "require"
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:43] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "("
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:43] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "::"
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:12:44] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:892\n"
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:44] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "ERROR: "
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:45] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    'ArgumentError: Package LanguageServer not found in current path:\n- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("LanguageServer")` to install the LanguageServer package.\n\nStacktrace:'
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:45] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "\n [1] "
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:45] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "require"
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:45] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "("
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:45] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "::"
[ERROR][2023-09-24 23:19:45] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:892\n"
```

Following the instruction on the [only similar issue on github](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/1848)
I ran the following

> julia --project=~/.julia/environments/nvim-lspconfig -e 'using Pkg;
> Pkg.add("LanguageServer")'

After which I have the following log errors

```
"WARNING: Threads.Mutex is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/farhaan/.julia/packages/SymbolServer/LMSFX/src/SymbolServer.jl:260\nWARNING: Threads.RecursiveSpinLock is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/farhaan/.julia/packages/SymbolServer/LMSFX/src/SymbolServer.jl:260\n"
[ERROR][2023-09-25 09:34:01] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "WARNING: Threads.Mutex is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/farhaan/.julia/packages/SymbolServer/LMSFX/src/SymbolServer.jl:260\nWARNING: Threads.RecursiveSpinLock is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/farhaan/.julia/packages/SymbolServer/LMSFX/src/SymbolServer.jl:260\n"
[ERROR][2023-09-25 09:34:01] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "WARNING: Threads.Mutex is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/farhaan/.julia/packages/SymbolServer/LMSFX/src/SymbolServer.jl:260\nWARNING: Threads.RecursiveSpinLock is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/farhaan/.julia/packages/SymbolServer/LMSFX/src/SymbolServer.jl:260\n"
[ERROR][2023-09-25 09:34:02] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:677    "rpc"   "/usr/bin/julia"    "stderr"    "WARNING: Threads.Mutex is deprecated, use ReentrantLock instead.\n  likely near /home/
```

Any further help is appreciated, as I have no idea where to go from here.